# Why the total degrees of freedom for repeated measures is not # of subjects minus one?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, independence

As an example, a single-factor repeated measures ANOVA:

Each subject is treated with levels of the single factor with each response recorded.

```
Subject    Placebo    Low Dose    High Dose
1          y11        y12         y13
2          y21        y22         y23
3          y31        y32         y33
4          y41        y42         y43
5          y51        y52         y53
6          y61        y62         y63
7          y71        y72         y73
8          y81        y82         y83

DF (total)            = 8*3 - 1   = 23
DF (between subjects) = 8 - 1     = 7
DF (within subjects)  = 8*(3 - 1) = 16
DF (treatments)       = 3 - 1     = 2
DF (error)            = 16 - 2    = 14
```

Since repeated measurements within subjects are not independent, why is the DF (total) treating them as if they are independent?

Does sphericity take the place of independence in repeated measures cases?